# How to Customize Featured Topics in Communities

Tags: community, napili, community-builder

I have users from different location logging into my community. Ex: Would like to display only couple of featured topics for users from region1 and rest to region2 users. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely through a custom theme layout, and you will have to replace the navBar topics to target the regions you want and load topics based on your criteria in a custom lightning component

[Create Custom Theme Layout Components for Communities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_theme_layout.htm)

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:themeLayout" access="global" description="Sample Custom Theme Layout">
    <aura:attribute name="search" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="profileMenu" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="navBar" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="newHeader" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <div>
        <div class="searchRegion">
            {!v.search}
        </div>
        <div class="profileMenuRegion">
            {!v.profileMenu}
        </div>
        <div class="navigation">
            {!v.navBar} ----> replace with your custom component
        </div>
        <div class="newHeader">
            {!v.newHeader}
        </div>
        <div class="mainContentArea">
            {!v.body}
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

for the custom navigational topics component, you can refer to:

[forceCommunity:navigationMenuBase](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_forceCommunity_navigationMenuBase.htm) and change the Navigation Menu component:

```
<aura:component extends="forceCommunity:navigationMenuBase" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <ul onclick="{!c.onClick}">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.menuItems}" var="item" >
            <aura:if isTrue="{!item.subMenu}">
                <li>{!item.label}</li>
                <ul>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!item.subMenu}" var="subItem">
                        <li><a data-menu-item-id="{!subItem.id}" href="">{!subItem.label}</a></li>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </ul>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <li><a data-menu-item-id="{!item.id}" href="">{!item.label}</a></li>
            </aura:set>
            </aura:if>
        </aura:iteration>
    </ul>
</aura:component>
```

controller:

```
({
    onClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        var id = event.target.dataset.menuItemId;
        if (id) {
            component.getSuper().navigate(id);
         }
   }
})
```

then, you will have to proceed with creating custom lightning components for the topics shown under the Topics catalog and detail page to reflect your requirements.